# POSTGRESQL - ERROR: source string too short for "YYYY" formatting field Problem

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

```
SELECT 
SUM (CASE WHEN (BANKCODE =1 OR IGBBANKCODE=1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)"ZİRAAT",
SUM (CASE WHEN (BANKCODE =1 OR IGBBANKCODE=1) THEN APPROVEDPRICE ELSE 0 END)/100 "ZİRAAT GELIR ",
SUM (CASE WHEN (BANKCODE =2 OR IGBBANKCODE=2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)"VAKIFBANK",
SUM (CASE WHEN (BANKCODE =2 OR IGBBANKCODE=2) THEN APPROVEDPRICE ELSE 0 END)/100 "VAKIFBANK GELIR ",
SUM (CASE WHEN (BANKCODE =4 OR IGBBANKCODE=4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)"ISBANK",
SUM (CASE WHEN (BANKCODE =4 OR IGBBANKCODE=4) THEN APPROVEDPRICE ELSE 0 END)/100 "ISBANK GELIR ",
SUM (CASE WHEN (BANKCODE =6 OR IGBBANKCODE=6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)"GARANTI",
SUM (CASE WHEN (BANKCODE =6 OR IGBBANKCODE=6) THEN APPROVEDPRICE ELSE 0 END)/100 "GARANTI GELIR ",
SUM (CASE WHEN (BANKCODE =7 OR IGBBANKCODE=7) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)"DENIZBANK",
SUM (CASE WHEN (BANKCODE =7 OR IGBBANKCODE=7) THEN APPROVEDPRICE ELSE 0 END)/100 "DENIZBANK GELIR ",
COUNT (*)"TOLAM", 
SUM (APPROVEDPRICE/100)"TOPLAM GELİR"
FROM KKMO.sap_transactions_view
WHERE TRANSACTIONTYPE <>20
AND (TABLETYPE='ET' OR IGBSYSTEMTYPE IN(0))
AND (PAYMENTDATE IS NOT NULL OR IGBPAYMENTTRANSFERDATE IS NOT NULL) 
AND (TO_TIMESTAMP(PAYMENTDATE::VARCHAR,'YYYYMMDD')::DATE= CURRENT_DATE OR TO_TIMESTAMP(IGBPAYMENTTRANSFERDATE::VARCHAR,'YYYYMMDD')::DATE= CURRENT_DATE)
```

```
ERROR:  source string too short for "YYYY" formatting field
DETAIL:  Field requires 4 characters, but only 1 remain.
HINT:  If your source string is not fixed-width, try using the "FM" modifier.
CONTEXT:  parallel worker
SQL state: 22007
```

Comment: Can you share sample values from column `IGBPAYMENTTRANSFERDATE`, `PAYMENTDATE`

Comment: Why are you storing date and timestamp values as strings? That is a **really**, really bad idea. And your current problem is a direct result of that design error. Do you have a chance to fix that and change those columns to `date` or `timestamp`

Answer (score 4):

There must be a row in your table where `paymentdate` contains a single character:

```
SELECT to_timestamp('7', 'YYYYMMDD');

ERROR:  source string too short for "YYYY" formatting field
DETAIL:  Field requires 4 characters, but only 1 remain.
HINT:  If your source string is not fixed-width, try using the "FM" modifier.
```

You need at least four, so for the year 7 A.D., use this:

```
SELECT to_timestamp('0007', 'YYYYMMDD');

         to_timestamp         
══════════════════════════════
 0007-01-01 00:00:00+01:05:21
(1 row)
```

Alternatively, as the error message tells you, use `FM`:

```
SELECT to_timestamp('7', 'FMYYYYMMDD');

         to_timestamp         
══════════════════════════════
 0007-01-01 00:00:00+01:05:21
(1 row)
```